# align output with printf

Tags: java, printf, alignment

Basically, I need to get the days to line up with the values side by side.
Like so:

```
Monday  273.44

Tuesday 568.4
```

Instead of

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday     
273.44
568.4
563.6
```

---

```
for (int p=0; p < days.length; p++)
{
    System.out.printf(days[p]);
}

for (int s=0; s < sales.length; s++)
{
    System.out.print( sales[s]);
}
```

Comment: That code does not produce that output. Please provide *correct* [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `printf` requires a format string, and multiple values. You're calling it entirely wrong. Perhaps you should (re)read the Java guide on how `printf` works.

Comment: I am assuming each day has its sales totals. So use the same for-loop to print the 'day' and its 'sales' on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%-10s` will make the days take exactly 10 spaces, even if they are shorter.

```
for (int p = 0; p < days.length; p++) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s%s%n", days[p], sales[p]);
}
```

Output

```
Monday    273.44
Tuesday   568.4
```

Comment: Prints `273.440000`, but OP seems to want `273.44`

Comment: @Andreas fixed that to 2 decimal places.. wondering how to remove that extra 0 from `568.40`

Comment: Use `%s` would print only needed decimals (but always at least one)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your output to be left-justified, you should try this

```
    for(int index = 0; index < days.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-9s" + " " + "%.2f%n",days[index], sales[index]);
    }
```

You need a minus sign for left-justified output followed by a number that indicates the width. In this case, we will use 9 because Wednesday is the day that has the largest character count among 7 potential days of the week.%s is a specifier for a string, %.2f is a specifier for a floating point with 2 decimal places, and %n is a specifier for printing new line. There is a lot of online resources that show you how to print formatted output in java using printf method, and I recommend you to do so.